# Rx BehaviorSubject + scan pushing prior event to new subscriber?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I want to have an stream to which I can push reducer functions. Each time a reducer function is pushed, a state object should be passed to the reducer, the reducer should return a modified state value, and the updated state should be pushed to subscribers. I'm hoping my code can explain:

```
import Rx from 'rx';
import { Map } from 'immutable';

let initialState = Map({ counter: 0 });

export let upstream = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(Rx.helpers.identity);
export let downstream = upstream.scan((state, reducer) => {
  return reducer(state);
}, initialState);

let increment = state => {
  return state.update('counter', counter => counter + 1);
};

upstream.onNext(increment);

downstream.subscribe(state => {
  console.log('subscriptionA', state.get('counter'));
});

upstream.onNext(increment);

setTimeout(() => {
  downstream.subscribe(state => {
    console.log('subscriptionB', state.get('counter'));
  });
}, 3000);
```

Here's the output I see:

```
subscriptionA 1
subscriptionA 2
subscriptionB 1
```

while I was hoping to see:

```
subscriptionA 1
subscriptionA 2
subscriptionB 2
```

Obviously I'm missing something fundamental here. It seems the `BehaviorSubject` is supposed to retain the latest value for new subscribers which would make me think that when `subscriptionB` subscribes to `downstream` that it would get the latest reduced value, but it looks like having the `.scan` in the middle fouls things up...or something.

What's going on here and how to I accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to see if everything is conform to your expectations if you replace

```
export let downstream = upstream.scan((state, reducer) => {
  return reducer(state);
}, initialState);
```

by

```
export let downstream = upstream.scan((state, reducer) => {
  return reducer(state);
}, initialState).shareReplay(1);
```

jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/cqaumutp/

If so, you are another victim of the hot vs. cold nature of `Rx.Observable`, or maybe more accurately the lazy instantiation of observables.

In short (not so short), what happens everytime you do a `subscribe`, is that a chain of observables is created by going upstream the chain of operators. Each operator subscribes to its source, and returns another observable up to the starting source. In your case, when you subscribe to `scan`, `scan` subscribes to `upstream` which is the last one. `upstream` being a subject, on subscription it just registers the subscriber. Other sources would do other things (like register a listener on a DOM node, or a socket, or whatever).

The point here is that every time you subscribe to the `scan`, you start anew, i.e. with the `initialState`. If you want to use the values from the first subscription to the `scan`, you have to use the `share` operator. On the first subscription to the `share`, it will pass your subscription request on to the `scan`. On the second and subsequent ones, it will not, it will register it, and forward to the associated observer all the values coming from the `scan` firstly subscribed to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I add `share()` then the result is:

    `subscriptionA 1`
    `subscriptionA 2`

I don't get any event through subscriptionB. I think your description makes some sense though and is helpful.

Comment: true, as because of the `share` you do not reach anymore the behaviour subject... but if you send something else on the next tick with `upstream.onNext` you should see it though that does not solve your problem. Then what I can think of is replace the `share` you put by `shareReplay(1)`. Shame there is no `jsfiddle` I would play with it on my side. If that works, then you do not need any more the behaviour subject.

Comment: `shareReplay(1)` seems to do the trick. Cf. `jsfiddle` here : http://jsfiddle.net/cqaumutp/. Click quickly four times on increment button, then wait for the timeout to expire and you should see subscription B with the right value. As you can see you do not need a behaviour subject anymore, the replay replace most of that functionality.

Comment: You're right. That's very enlightening and it makes sense. Thank you and thanks for putting in the work to produce the jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that seems to be giving me the results I'm looking for. I would appreciate it if others could verify that it's an appropriate solution.

```
import Rx from 'rx';
import { Map } from 'immutable';

let initialState = Map({ counter: 0 });

export let upstream = new Rx.Subject();

let downstreamSource = upstream.scan((state, reducer) => {
  return reducer(state);
}, initialState);

export let downstream = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(initialState);
downstreamSource.subscribe(downstream);

let increment = state => {
  return state.update('counter', counter => counter + 1);
};

upstream.onNext(increment);

downstream.subscribe(state => {
  console.log('subscriptionA', state.get('counter'));
});

upstream.onNext(increment);

setTimeout(() => {
  downstream.subscribe(state => {
    console.log('subscriptionB', state.get('counter'));
  });
}, 3000);
```