# Building MVI loop with RxJava: how to replace BehaviorSubject with scan()

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to figure out a way to eliminate mutable state and therefore possible race condition. But I can't seem to figure out how to somehow "intertwine" two Observables, while also using "scan".

Hopefully by showing more code I can give you the idea:

```
private val stateRelay: BehaviorRelay<State> = BehaviorRelay.createDefault(initialState ?: DEFAULT_STATE) // maybe this should be `Observable.startWith()` somehow?

fun bindIntents(intents: Observable<Actions>, stateRenderer: StateRenderer) {
    compositeDisposable += intents.concatMap { action ->
        when (action) {
            is Actions.Increment -> {
                Observable.create<Change> { emitter -> 
                   // emit things
                }
            }
            is Actions.Decrement -> {
                Observable.create<Change> { emitter -> 
                   // emit things
                }
            }
        }
    }.map { change ->
        reducer(stateRelay.value, change) // TODO: figure out how to use scan() here, instead of stateRelay.value! :(
    }.subscribeBy { newState ->
        stateRelay.accept(newState) // there is a chance that the relay shouldn't be here if scan is used
    }

    compositeDisposable += 
        stateRelay // TODO: figure out how to use scan() instead of a relay!
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribeBy { state ->
                stateRenderer(state)
            }
}

fun unbindIntents() {
    compositeDisposable.clear()
}
```

So I'm receiving a `Observable<Actions>` in this method, which is technically a `PublishRelay` on the other side (this should be fine).

However, somehow I'm supposed to replace the `BehaviorRelay` with `Observable.scan()` (possibly with `startWith`) to eliminate the mutable state, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what I'm supposed to do for that to happen.

As for the types involved, in case they are needed:

```
private typealias Reducer = (state: State, change: Change) -> State

private typealias StateRenderer = (state: State) -> Unit

@Parcelize
data class State(val count: Int): Parcelable
```

---

How could I wrap `intents.concatMap.map`, as part of an  `Observable.scan()` (with possibly `startWith()` and `replay(1)`), to eliminate my usage of the BehaviorSubject?

Comment: I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114347/rx-behaviorsubject-scan-pushing-prior-event-to-new-subscriber which was similar but it is RxJS and not entirely applicable.

Comment: the map part of `intents.concatMap.map` should be replaced with `.scan(initialState, { currentState, change -> reducer(currentState, change)` and also remove the subscribeBy there. That block now returns an Observable<Change> instead of a disposable. Put that observable in the place of the stateRelay in the second bit and you're basically done.

Comment: Sorry, I of course meant that the `.scan` bit returns an `Observable<State>`

Comment: @Liminal I've been making some tweaks but I can't seem to figure out what I should be calling `observable.scan()` on. I have edited the question with the changes I've made since - for example, merging the two observables as you mentioned.

Comment: With some research, apparently I need to somehow apply the same thing that RxFeedback does: https://github.com/NoTests/RxFeedback.swift/blob/master/Sources/RxFeedback/ObservableType%2BRxFeedback.swift#L34-L56

Comment: perhaps you can emit the `reducer` instead of `change`, then in `scan` you will receive _reducers_, which you can then apply to the state from the `scan` to return a new `state`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll elaborate on my comment above.
This is a simple rewrite of your code to do what you're asking for.

```
fun bindIntents(intents: Observable<Actions>, stateRenderer: StateRenderer) {
    val stateObservable = intents.concatMap { action ->
        when (action) {
            is Actions.Increment -> {
                Observable.create<Change> { emitter ->
                // emit things
                }
            }
            is Actions.Decrement -> {
                Observable.create<Change> { emitter ->
                    // emit things
                }
            }
        }
    }.scan(initialState, { currentState, change -> reducer(currentState, change)})

    compositeDisposable +=
        stateObservable
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .subscribeBy { state ->
                    stateRenderer(state)
                }
}
```

note that this can be simplified further by inlining the observable I assign to `stateObservable` in the expression below and using a method reference as the second argument to scan like this

```
fun bindIntents(intents: Observable<Actions>, stateRenderer: StateRenderer) {
    compositeDisposable +=
            intents.concatMap { action ->
                when (action) {
                    is Actions.Increment -> {
                        Observable.create<Change> { emitter ->
                            // emit things
                        }
                    }
                    is Actions.Decrement -> {
                        Observable.create<Change> { emitter ->
                            // emit things
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.scan(initialState, this::reducer)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .subscribeBy { state ->
                        stateRenderer(state)
                    }
}
```

Comment: Huh. So you really just had to swap out the `map(reducer) { getValue() ` with `scan(initialState, reducer)` and it works. And I was so close too... Thanks! :D

Comment: I also added a `replay(1).autoConnect(0)` at the end and it seems to be correct.